# How to sort a CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sorting, checkedlistbox

I have a **CheckedListBox** that looks like this :

- Fruits
- .....*Banana*
- .....*Apple*
- Countries
- Cars
- .....*Maruti*
- .....*Toyota*
- Planes
- Students
- Animals

Though the ones italicized are not actually child nodes but are considered as child nodes of the parent. Eg. *Banana* & *Apple* are children of Fruits, so they go together etc.

Direct sort doesn't work as this will not sort keeping the child nodes with their parent.
I have to sort it in such a way that the child nodes remain with their respective parents, the parents are sorted and so are the children within each parent.

For Eg. the o/p should be

- Animals
- Cars
- .....*Maruti*
- .....*Toyota*
- Countries
- Fruits
- .....*Apple*
- .....*Banana*
- Planes
- Students

Comment: CheckedListBox provides the option of check boxes in the form of a list, treeview is completely different from what I need.

Comment: I have no idea that what your comment mean? `TreeView` also [provides checkboxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.checkboxes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you are interested in that.

Comment: Project (a large scale one) has already been done and a lot of dependencies exist on the CheckedListBox. So I HAVE to apply sorting on this only. Is it possible in any way??

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I think he is working on a pre-built project and as a maintenance work, he has to apply sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a List<String> where each parent string is unchanged and each child has the parent as a prefix.

- Fruits
- Fruits Banana
- Fruits Apple
- Countries
- Cars
- Cars Maruti
- Cars Toyota
- Planes

After you sort this (alphabetically), the parent will be sorted to be just in front of the children. Then rebuild the CheckedListBox.Items from the sorted List<String>.

In case there is potential ambiguity you may want to use a different separator, some character not used otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

As Noted in the Comments, you could probably use a tree-view to show this relationship better. [You can put check boxes on nodes in a treeview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.checkboxes(v=vs.110).aspx)
Sorting will then be a bit more implicit with what you are doing, and the relationship will be more visible.

However.
If you *do* wish to use custom sorting for your CheckedListBox, you will probably have to create your own control Derived from CheckedListBox, and [override the "Sort" Method to provide your own sorting methodology.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sort(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// This class inherits from CheckedListBoxand implements a different  
// sorting method. 
public class SortSpecialCheckedListBox:
    CheckedListBox

{
    public SortSpecialCheckedListBox() : base()
    {        
    }

    // Overrides the parent class Sort to perform the specialised sorting
    // behaviour you are interested in
    protected override void Sort()
    {
        // Do your specialised sort here.
    }
}
```